# MySQL query only completing 80% of the query, why is it missing the 20% out?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that `UPDATE`'s columns in a table.

```
$sql = $con->query("UPDATE projects SET 
                ProjectName = '{$UpdatePName}', 
                StartDate = '{$UpdatePStart}', 
                EndDate = '{$UpdatePEnd}', 
                AStartDate = '{$UpdateAStart}',
                AEndDate = '{$UpdateAEnd}',
                ProjectBio = '{$UpdateBio}'
            WHERE ProjectID = '$Project'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

However it is not updating `StartDate` and `EndDate`. It used to update before I added `AStartDate` and `AEndDate`, but I don't see how they would impact it?

I have checked for spelling mistakes etc, so hoping I've not missed anything obvious.

The whole section of code below:

```
$Project = $_GET['id'];

    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE ProjectID ='$Project'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    if ($result){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $_SESSION["ProID"] = $row['ProjectID'];
    $_SESSION["ProName"] = $row['ProjectName'];
    $_SESSION["PStDate"] = $row['StartDate'];
    $_SESSION["PEnDate"] = $row['EndDate']; 
    $_SESSION["ProBio"] = $row['ProjectBio'];
    $_SESSION["AStDate"] = $row['AStartDate'];
    $_SESSION["AEnDate"] = $row['AEndDate']; 
    }

if(isset($_POST['Update'])){

//Ternary expressions to switch between POST or SESSION variables.
$UpdatePName =  ($_POST['ProjName'] != '' )? $_POST['ProjName'] : $_SESSION["ProName"];

$UpdatePStart = ($_POST['StarDate'] != '' )? $_POST['StarDate'] : $_SESSION["PStDate"];

$UpdatePEnd =   ($_POST['EnDate'] != '' )? $_POST['EnDate'] : $_SESSION["PEnDate"];

$UpdateBio =    ($_POST['ProDesc'] != '' )? $_POST['ProDesc'] : $_SESSION["ProBio"];

$UpdateAStart = ($_POST['ActStartDate'] != '' )? $_POST['ActStartDate'] : $_SESSION["AStDate"];

$UpdateAEnd =   ($_POST['ActEndDate'] != '' )? $_POST['ActEndDate'] : $_SESSION["AEnDate"];

$sql = $con->query("UPDATE projects SET 
                    ProjectName = '{$UpdatePName}', 
                    StartDate = '{$UpdatePStart}', 
                    EndDate = '{$UpdatePEnd}', 
                    AStartDate = '{$UpdateAStart}',
                    AEndDate = '{$UpdateAEnd}',
                    ProjectBio = '{$UpdateBio}'
                    WHERE ProjectID = '$Project'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

header('Location: Projects.php');
die();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the values are being set in the session? I'd also suggest taking advantage of mysqli's parameter binding, otherwise you're wide open for sql injection.

Comment: You can activate mysql's [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) and check what query/data actually arrived at the server.

Comment: `$UpdatePStart` vs `$UpdateStart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a mismatch in the variable names in your code, while setting the variables in case update post variable is set you are setting the variables ***$UpdateStart, $UpdateEnd*** instead of ***$UpdatePStart, $UpdatePEnd*** due to which it always remains the same as the value obtained from DB and never getting updated.

```
$UpdatePStart = $_SESSION["PStDate"];
if ($_POST['StarDate'] != '' ) { 
       $UpdateStart = $_POST['StarDate'];}
$UpdatePEnd = $_SESSION["PEnDate"];
 if ($_POST['EnDate'] != '' ) { 
          $UpdateEnd = $_POST['EnDate'];}
```

should be :

```
$UpdatePStart = $_SESSION["PStDate"];
    if ($_POST['StarDate'] != '' ) { 
           $UpdatePStart = $_POST['StarDate'];}
    $UpdatePEnd = $_SESSION["PEnDate"];
     if ($_POST['EnDate'] != '' ) { 
              $UpdatePEnd = $_POST['EnDate'];}
```

Comment: Ahh well spotted! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a clear doubt that, these two session value are set or not ? because these are your new columns in the table so my be null

```
$_SESSION["AStDate"] = $row['AStartDate'];
$_SESSION["AEnDate"] = $row['AEndDate'];
```

So before using them in `UPDATE` query , try to print `$UpdateAStart` & `$UpdateAEnd`

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer... it's just a shot in the dark.